# Compact embedding of $H^1(0,+\infty)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is the following embedding compact ?

$$H^1(0,+\infty) \rightarrow L^p(0,+\infty), \text{ with } p>1 $$

Comment: What is $H^1$ in this context? Sobolev space? or some version of Hardy space?

Comment: Is the sobolev space

Comment: For the embedding you need $p\geq 2$ and it is never compact. Just consider $u_n(x)=u(x-n)$ with $u$ non zero and with compact support.

Comment: Ok, thank you sir. Is there a functional space $Y$ such that $H^1(0,+\infty)$ is embedded in $Y$ compactly ?